# Como hacer proxy con python3?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, proxy

Paso a comentar mi situacion. Hice 4 scripts para raspar algunas paginas web con selenium. El siguiente paso era contratar un vps y hacer que esos 4 scripts corran en automatico para que realizen las tareas todos los dias, sin depender de mi. El problema que me encuentro ahora es que ese vps, cuando quiero hacer peticiones con python, me tira error la pagina, digamos que por la ip de ese vps, la pagina esta bloqueada, esto lo se por que ingrese a la pagina web desde chrome, y si, esta bloqueada esa ip, pero instalando un VPN en el NAVEGADOR CHROME, y colocando ese VPN en la locazion MEXICO, si ingresa a la pagina, pero claro, al efectuar mi script en python me da error ya que justo ese script, hace peticiones desde python y selenium lo uso para enviar esa informacion a otra pagina web.
Los otros 3 script no hay problema por que lo pude solucionar, como ya mencione, instalando el VPN en chrome y dando hubicacion en mexico. Selenium ingresa a la pagina, obtiene unos datos, y los envia a otra pagina web. Pero con este scrip en particular no me deja por que la peticion la hace desde python y despude uso selenium para enviar esa informacion a otra pagina.

Lo que necesito es saber si puedo modiciar ese script insertandole un proxy, mayormente de mexico, por que se que con esa ip funciona, para que python puede obtener informacion de la pagina y depsues continiaur con mi scrip.

Se puede hacer?

Comment: SI tienes la VPN instalada como una extensión de Chrome haz la solicitud desde el navegador. Puedes ejecutar *javascript* en el navegador pasando un `str` al método  `execute_script` del *webdriver*, y hacer una petición con `fetch` o `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: gracias, ya lo solucione colocando u vpn en chrome pero editando todo el codigo, gracias.